# Pass array on adhadler event

Tags: arrays, vb.net, parameters

My code

```
Public Class LoadPictureBox

    Public Shared Sub Create(panel As Panel, array() As Movie, PosY As Integer)

        'Check height of the Movies Panel
        If array.Length Mod 5 = 0 Then
            panel.Height = (array.Length / 5 * 293) + 100
        Else
            panel.Height = (((array.Length \ 5) + 1) * 293) + 100
        End If

        'Places Labels for each movie
        Dim PosX = 50

        For index As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
            Dim MovieBox As New PictureBox With {
                    .BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                    .Size = New Size(182, 268),
                    .Location = New Point(PosX, PosY),
                    .Cursor = Cursors.Hand,
                    .Image = My.Resources._200,
                    .ImageLocation = array(index).Url
            }

            panel.Controls.Add(MovieBox)
            MovieBox.TabIndex = index

            'Add pictureBoxs on array
            array(index).P = MovieBox

            'Adds click even for every label
            AddHandler MovieBox.Click, AddressOf AllMoviesCLick

            PosX += 245
            If (index + 1) Mod 5 = 0 Then
                PosY += 293
                PosX = 50
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I want to pass The `array(index) As Movie` as parameter to `AddHandler MovieBox.Click, AddressOf AllMoviesCLick`

Something Like `AddHandler MovieBox.Click, AddressOf AllMoviesCLick(array(index))`

Class movie

```
Public Class Movie

    Private mid As Integer
    Private mtitle As String
    Private myear As String
    Private mdescription As String
    Private mrating As Double
    Private mURL As String
    Private mP As PictureBox
```

So i can use something like array.id etc

It's my first time asking something here and i have looked for it everywere and i didnt find any solution

Comment: That's not how it works. Handle the event as normal and then write code in the method to get the data from a field or whatever. You can't arbitrarily pass data to event handlers. The event handler MUST have the correct signature for the event, which is (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) for a Click event. Maybe you need to assign the data to the Tag of the control and get it back from there via the sender parameter, which is the object that raised the event.

Comment: You don't want to *pass The array(index) As Movie as parameter to AddHandler MovieBox.Click*, you probably want to know which Movie class object the PictureBox selected belongs to. You can handle the `MouseClick` event in the Movie class. Add, e.g., a Constructor to the class that accepts a PictureBox as parameter. Set the reference to the `mP` property and subscribe to event there. BTW, you also probably want a `List(Of Movie)`, not an array. + Use a TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel to automate the layout of your Controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *Lambda* `Sub` to call directly your `AllMoviesCLick` passing your parameters:

```
 'Here your AddHandler 
 AddHandler MovieBox.Click, Sub() AllMoviesCLick(array(index))

 'Then here your method AllMoviesCLick
  Private Sub AllMoviesCLick(movie As Movie)
      Console.WriteLine("movie id: " & movie.Whatever.ToString())
  End Sub
```

Comment: Withdrawn, it seems like it's allowed with a lambda, possibly precisely because a lambda could never be removed anyway.  It works differently when you try to use AddressOf.